# Unable to use session in Pagemodel even after configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use HttpContext.Session in my asp.net core web application but I'm having trouble. Accessing the session results in InvalidOperationException, with the message "Session has not been configured for this application or request".

I've search around and there some code you have to add to start up i.e adding session and uses it. (I've also added Nuget package AspNetCore.Session).

Now when I try to access Session (HttpContext.Session) in my PageModel code-behind. It throws exception with the message as specified in paragraph above. I can't find any more details aside from you gotta set up in startup code which I've done. My startup code is below:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Page model on post is how i'm trying to access it:

```
        public async void OnPostAsync()
        {
            //Some async stuff here.
            //Session throws exception
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("something", "something");
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't seem to access the static `Session` via `HttpContext`, what you need to do is in `ConfigurationServices` method add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` This will let you inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your page model constructor, this will have session that you setup instead.

Makre sure you set the Session as a member variable in the constructor, as accessing it via HttpSession in the Post method would result in the same problem.